# regex exact match multiple search words using jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using jQuery. I have to check if a given list of words are in a paragraph or not. I want the exact match of a word or a phrase(whole word match).ie, if i search for 'be' in 'Be a bee', only one match is there. I have done like this.

```
var searchText="tool,media,be,team";
var regexExactMatch = new RegExp('\^' + searchText.split(",").join("|") + '\$');
if (regexExactMatch.test(item.Name))
{
//Found
}
```

It is working for one search term, ie, without any comma (eg: media).
But for comma separated search, it will break.

How to do a exact match search for multiple search terms. I'm very very new to regex. Also I have to do the same search for integers and date (`MM/dd/yyyy`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `new RegExp('^(?:' + searchText.split(",").join("|") + ')$');`. Otherwise, the anchors are applied respectively to the first and last alternatives only.

Comment: why not put these Strings in an array?

Comment: That's not jQuery... JavaScript it is.

Comment: Actually, I find the question rather unclear. What do you mean by *exact match*? A *whole word match* or *full string match*? For whole word search replace `^` and `$` with `\\b`.

Comment: @stribizhev  ('^(?:' + searchText.split(",").join("|") + ')$'); is working. can u write it as answer

Comment: I posted an answer, though I would not have done if I knew you prefer the other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `^` from the beginning and `$` from the end of the RegExp. Like this :

```
var regexExactMatch = new RegExp(searchText.split(",").join("|"));
```

**Reason**

`^` will set the condition that the matched text need to be at the beginning of the string and `$` set the condition that the matched text need to be at the end of the string, which can only happen if there is only that text in the string.

Comment: With your approach, the leading `(` and trailing `)` are redundant. #2 is plain wrong.

Comment: [`tool|media`](https://regex101.com/r/nD5zO4/1) will match either `tool` or `media`. [`too(l|m)edia`](https://regex101.com/r/nD5zO4/2) will match either `tooledia` or `toomedia`.

Answer (score 3):

For *full input string match* use

```
new RegExp('^(?:' + searchText.split(",").join("|") + ')$');
             ^^^                                       ^
```

For a whole word search, replace `^` and `$` with `\b`:

```
new RegExp('\\b(?:' + searchText.split(",").join("|") + ')\\b');
```

Otherwise, the anchors are applied respectively to the first and last alternatives only (i.e. your regex will look like `/^tool|media|be|team$/` looking for `tool` at the beginning only, `media` and `be` anywhere in the string and `team` only at the end of the string).

Note I am using `(?:...)` non-capturing group since grouping is only necessary here, not capturing (no storing of the submatch). If you need to access the matched text, you can access the 0th group that equals the whole match.

Also, you do not need those `\`s before `^` and `$`, they are not necessary at all and are ignored in the constructor notation since there are no escape sequences like `\^` and `\$`.